# Change Dynamically the BoundFields in a GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a `GridView` inside a `UpdatePanel`. In some cases, I have to show different columns in this `GridView` so I need to change the `BoundFields` that are specified in my `aspx`.

How can I change the `BoundFields` to make the `GridView` be filled for a different query and different fields ?

**ASPX**

```
<cc1:GridView ID="grdImoveis" CssClass="StyleGrid" Width="100%" runat="server" ShowHeader="false"
            AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="dsGrid" BorderWidth="0px" GridLines="None"
            AllowPaging="True" EnableModelValidation="True" >
            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" CssClass="EstiloDalinhaAlternativaGrid" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <RowStyle CssClass="EstiloDalinhaGrid" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Nome" DataField="NomeCompleto" />
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Cargo" DataField="DescricaoCargo1" />
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Data Cadastro" DataField="DataHora" />
                <asp:TemplateField ControlStyle-CssClass="acoes_lista_imovel" HeaderText="Curso">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <div class="acoes_lista_imovel">
                            <%# montaIcones(Eval("Usuario_Id").ToString())%>
                        </div>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </cc1:GridView>
```

**CODE BEHIND**

```
protected void btnSelecionarData_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        string select = string.Empty;
        select += "SELECT San_Credenciada.Apelido, San_Usuario.NomeCompleto, San_Usuario.Usuario_Id, San_Usuario.DescricaoCargo1, "
            + "CONVERT(varchar, San_Usuario.DataHora, 103) AS DataHora, San_UsuarioCurso.Cv, San_UsuarioCurso.Institucional, "
            + "San_UsuarioCurso.Copon, San_UsuarioCurso.ManualCaptacaoESistema, San_UsuarioCurso.PosturaProfissional, San_UsuarioCurso.Certificado "
            + "FROM San_Usuario "
            + "JOIN San_Credenciada "
            + "ON San_Usuario.Credenciada_Id = San_Credenciada.Credenciada_Id "
            + "JOIN San_UsuarioCurso "
            + "ON San_Usuario.Usuario_Id = San_UsuarioCurso.Usuario_Id "
            + "WHERE San_Usuario.Provisorio = 1 "
            + "AND San_Usuario.Excluido = 0 "
            + "AND San_UsuarioCurso.DataCurso = '" + this.DtBusca.Value.ToString() +"' "
            + "GROUP BY San_Credenciada.Apelido, San_Usuario.NomeCompleto, San_Usuario.Usuario_Id, "
            + "San_Usuario.DescricaoCargo1, San_Usuario.DataHora, San_UsuarioCurso.Cv, San_UsuarioCurso.Institucional, "
            + "San_UsuarioCurso.Copon, San_UsuarioCurso.ManualCaptacaoESistema, San_UsuarioCurso.PosturaProfissional, San_UsuarioCurso.Certificado "
            + "ORDER BY San_Usuario.DataHora ASC ";

        dsGrid.ConnectionString = c.Con;
        dsGrid.SelectCommand = select;
        dsGrid.Dispose();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your query correctly, you want to change columns. A simple solution for this is that `do not specify fields in your aspx page, just set AutoGenrateColumns = True` in your grid view decleratoin
Your grid should look like

```
<asp:GridView ID="gv" runat="server" AutoGenrateColumns="True" />

// Now in your code behind just specify its DataSource property it will fill up with your desired columns.
// Your query should contain only those columns which you want to show
```

Comment: But this will generate all columns that exist in my query, and in a specific column I put a image

Comment: yes, otherwise you have to use RowDataBound event of your grid to change it. What do you want to change ? Column Header ? or what

Comment: For example, `SELECT Id, Name FROM User`, if I put this query to fill a `GridView` with `AutoGenerateColumn = true` will give me just Id and Name columns. I need to put another column with a specific image in all rows in this column.

Comment: from where will you get the image path ?

Comment: The image has a reference in my solution in VisualStudio, and are in my C: and in the server

Comment: One another way is that first you save your data in a datatable object. Add the no.of columns you want in your datatable then assign it to the gridview. Example: ` Datatable dt=new DataTable(); dt.Columns.Add("ID"); dt.Columns.Add("Image"). ........` and then assign the data and finally set it to the DataSource of your gridview.

Answer (score 1):

you can put GridView and Enable "AutoGenerateColumns=True" and for each case that you like fill grid view.

Comment: But this will generate all columns that exist in my query

Comment: you can create bounded field Programmatically(use BoundField's class)

Comment: see here : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13461/how-to-create-columns-dynamically-in-a-grid-view

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code for create ImageField Programmatically :

```
 ImageField img = new ImageField();
        img.HeaderText = "Pictuer";
        img.DataImageUrlField ="Pic";
        img.DataImageUrlFormatString = "images\\{0}";
        GridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
        GridView1.Columns.Add(img);
```